400 Bad request with Xbox Live authentication API
I am attempted to provide a login via Minecraft for my website however keep running into the same error with the Xbox Live API. I first am request an access token from https://login.microsoftonline.com/consumers/oauth2/v2.0/authorize which works fine and returns a code in the query parameters.
However when I try to make a second request to https://user.auth.xboxlive.com/user/authenticate with that code, I get a 400: Bad Request error every time. My Google searches seem to point to missing Content-Type and Accept headers but I have both of them included, and have even tried to perform the request on Postman to check and I get the same issue.
This is the full code:
const access_token = url.searchParams.get("code");
const xbox_auth = await fetch("https://user.auth.xboxlive.com/user/authenticate", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json", "Accept": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        Properties: {
            AuthMethod: "RPS",
            SiteName: "user.auth.xboxlive.com",
            RpsTicket: `d=${access_token}` // your access token from the previous step here
        },
        RelyingParty: "http://auth.xboxlive.com",
        TokenType: "JWT"
    }),
});
const json = await xbox_auth.json();

The 400 error code suggests there is an error in the syntax somewhere but I have no clue where.
